# How to log to a different file inside a Command?

Tags: php, logging, symfony, symfony-2.1, monolog

I'm creating a [custom command](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/console/console_command.html), and I want to use a different log file.

In the docs it says that I have to [tag](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-monolog) my service. But my custom command isn't a service, is it? Should I make it a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I pushed NullHandler to invalidate the other handlers. Then I added one handler for info messages<strike>, and another one for all messages, that only triggers if there is a warning, error, etc</strike>.

```
$logger = $this->getContainer()->get('logger');
$logger->pushHandler(new NullHandler);
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('app/logs/mycommand.log', Logger::DEBUG));
//$logger->pushHandler(new FingersCrossedHandler(new StreamHandler('app/logs/mycommand.log', Logger::DEBUG), Logger::WARNING, 0, false)); // does not work. It prevents INFO messages from being logged
```

Answer (score 1):

The second document is for the case when you want to create a custom logger. But if you just want to change the file where the log is saved, you don´t need to do that, you just need to set the monolog 'path' configuration. For more info, see [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/monolog.html)

Also, The object you retrieve when you get('logger') is derived from the class Monolog\Logger. That class has two methods: pushHandler() to add a handler to the handler stack and popHandler() to remove a handler to the handler stack. Maybe in your command you could pop all the standard handlers and then push an instance of Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler with your custom path.

Comment: But I want to use dev.log/app.log for http requests, and command.log for my custom command. Inside my command I do `$this->getContainer()->get('logger')`. So how do I tell it to use a different handler there? Even if I configure it like in your link I will have to do something else.